# Edit and Delete the particular user without using admin panel in django

Tags: django

I have created my models using django user model. I am able to perform the edit functionality to the created form.Now i want to do DELETE the particular user details by using DELETE button.Here is my code

forms.py

```
class EditProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name','last_name','username','email','password']
        help_texts={
            'username': None
        }
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
    form = GithubInfo(request.POST)
    name=''
    if form.is_valid():
        name = form.cleaned_data.get("name") 
        form.save()
    context = {'form':form , 'name':name}
    return render(request,'signupapp/index.html',context)

def edit_profile(request):
    user = request.user
    form = EditProfileForm(request.POST or None, initial={'first_name':user.first_name, 'last_name':user.last_name, 'username':user.username, 'email':user.email, 'password':user.password})
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            user.first_name = request.POST['first_name']
            user.last_name = request.POST['last_name']
            user.username = request.POST['username']
            user.email = request.POST['email']
            user.password = request.POST['password']
            user.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('signupapp:index'))
    context = {"form": form}
    return render(request, "signupapp/edit_profile.html", context)



def delete_profile(request, username):
    profile = UserProfileInfo.objects.get(username=username)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        profile.delete()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('signupapp:index'))
    return render(request, "signupapp/delete_profile.html", {'profile': profile})
```

edit_profile.html

```
<form method="POST" action="" class="" >
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

delete_profile.html

```
 <form action="" method ="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p>Are you sure to delete "{{UserProfileInfo.username}}"?</p>
    <input type="submit" value="Delete"/>
</form>
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^index/$',views.index,name='index'),
url(r'^edit/$', views.edit_profile, name='edit'),
url(r'^delete/<str:username>/$', views.delete_profile, name='delete')
```

here are my edit and delete links for editing and deleting the details in

index.html

```
<h1>Welcome!</h1>
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<h3>Firstname: {{ user.first_name }}</h3>
<h3>Lastname: {{ user.last_name }}</h3>
<h3>Username: {{ user.username }}</h3>
<h3>Email: {{ user.email }}</h3>
{% else %}
<h2>Register or Login if you'd like to</h2>
{% endif %}
<a href="{% url 'signupapp:edit' %}"><input type="button" value="Edit"/></a>
<a href="{% url 'signupapp:delete' %}"><input type="button" value="Delete"/></a>
```

When I run this code on server i am getting this error

```
TypeError at /delete/
delete_profile() missing 1 required positional argument: 'username'
```

Can anyone help me to overcome this error.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't create a delete method/functionality in your edit_profile method. Instead create a different method called delete_user or something like that and complete your logic there. The most simpel thing is to pass a id of the user through and then delete it by it's id. For example Model.objects.filter(id=id).delete() or something like that.

Comment: yeah it should be done.But i need to display edit and delete buttons in edit_profile page.But i need, when i click the delete button the details of the particular user must delete in the database also.So for that purpose I am asking it.

Comment: you have to pass the `username` in your `delete_profile` url pattern also.

Comment: Sorry i forget to add the edited url. After passing username to the url patter i am getting the same error.How can i solve it.

Comment: @Saif i think it should be `<str:username>` instead of `<username>` since username is a string

Comment: After adding <str:username> also it  showing the same error..

Comment: where is your link to for the delete in your template?Did you pass the username in the delete link

Comment: I added my delete link.Check it once

Comment: `<a href="{% url 'signupapp:delete' u.username %}">` change your url like this

Comment: It is giving error like this NoReverseMatch at /index/
Reverse for 'delete' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['delete/<str:username>/$']

Comment: @Saif try doing `<a href="{% url 'signupapp:delete' request.user.username %}">` in your delete link

Comment: It's also not working.Raising the same error..

Comment: @Saif  where is your view that render the delete link ?

Comment: I changed my code.Check it once

Comment: that was not i was asking i was asking for the view which render this `<a href="{% url 'signupapp:delete' %}">` delete link

Comment: you have to pass that `profile` through context instead of just `context=context` and also you need to change url to `<a href="{% url 'signupapp:delete' profile.username %}">`

Comment: By doing like that it's raising error like this   NoReverseMatch at /index/
Reverse for 'delete' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['delete/<str:username>/$']

Comment: Not working.I think there is something error in delete_profile view

Answer (score 1):

Change your views like this:

```
 def edit_profile(request):
        user = request.user
        if request.method == 'POST':
           form = EditProfileForm(request.POST or None,instance= user)

            if form.is_valid():
               user = form.save()

               user.save()
               return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('signupapp:index'))
       else:
          form = EditProfileForm()
       return render(request, "signupapp/edit_profile.html", {'form':form,'user':user})
```

And in your template pass the requested user value like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="" class="" >
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type='text' name = 'first_name' value={{user.first_name}}
  <input type='text' name = 'lastt_name' value={{user.last_name}}
 .............................
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

For delete you can do like this.

```
def delete_profile(request, username):
    user = UserProfileInfo.objects.get(username=username)
    if user:
          user.delete()
          messages.success(request,'user with username {} deleted'.format(user.username))
          return redirect('redirect where you want')
    else:
        messages.error(request,'no user found')
        return redirect('redirect where you want')
```